# How to make custom page link to root automatically?

Tags: permalinks, server, home-url

I've put `/` in my Home custom page link, and locally my server is `localhost:3000` and it works fine, but on my server the url is `www.mysite.com/theproject`, but `/` there does not lead to `www.mysite.com/theproject` but to `www.mysite.com`, but for example the logo which has a link like so `<?= esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>` works fine on the server.

Any way to make the custom page link behave like it has `<?= esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>` ?

Comment: `/theproject` ?

Comment: yes, the website itself is not hosted at the root of the server but in a subfolder

Comment: Yeah I know, I'm saying... make your custom link, `/theproject` or use the `nav_menu_link_attributes` filter to change the `href' of the specific item. You can also set a home link that will resolve to the base path of your installation by using the Menu manager in the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

For the url to the root of the Wordpress installation you can use:

```
<?php echo site_url(); ?>
```

see: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url

Edit: please check your url settings in the general Wordpress settings.